# Why is program called Geany invoked when I try to debug on server in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, servlets, geany

I have a servlet and following the instructions for Eclipse, I select this servlet and choose debug on server. Then I start the server (Tomcat 7 running on Centos). At this point I would have expected the server running the code to stop at the breakpoint I chose but instead a program/IDE call Geany starts up and I have no idea what to do with it. Three questions:

1. Didn't debugging servlets on Tomcat work without Geany?
2. Can we still do it without Geany?
3. If not, can you please explain what Geany is and how to use it to step through code, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you debug you servlets in detail? There you will find the reason I'm pretty sure.

Comment: As I mention below, skipped the web.xml step -- everything is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that I made a simple mistake in the web.xml file -- so a partial answer to my question is that using Eclipse and Tomcat I was able to debug the servlet code just like any other code, no need to set up remote debugging or anything.

Have said the above, the Geany thing was a surprise -- I don't need to know any more about Geany now but maybe others do.

Answer (score -1):

I would say Geany is a default program for running servlet or another step you mentioned. I would check Geany options and would try to uncheck everything *with word run as a default*.

It is running automatically because there is somewhere in the Geany settings option marked to run "some" files as a default program.

I would also check Cent OS settings and check default applications for the system.

Comment: No, this isn't true. Geany is not adding itself to anything as default app. Even not under Windows.